# Showing a gray backdrop with a mixin

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a small window that I'm inserting into my page (and removing when the page is closed). I want a grayed-out background behind this window, as on dialogs. So I thought I'd use `paper-dialog-behavior` or `iron-overlay-behavior` as a mixin, and set `this.withBackdrop = true` in my `ready()` method. However, when I add `...extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior], Polymer.Element)` or `...extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.PaperDialogBehaviorImpl], Polymer.Element)` to this element, it never appears.

I tired `.open()` like on a dialog and was told that it's undefined. I can trace my element loading in DevTools, and no errors print in the console, but it never appears on the screen.

You can see what I'm going for at this pen: https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/zRLMpe
If I swap the class declarations of `MyChild` for the one with the mixin, the child loads but never displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `open` of `MyChild` after append:

```
_doTap(e) {
   . . .
   this.$.placeholder.appendChild(this.mychild);
   this.mychild.open()
}
```

Then add `withBackdrop` property to `true` in `MyChild` component:

```
static get properties() {
     return {
         withBackdrop: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: true
        }
     }
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/stat92/pen/RQYvdv?editors=1000) you'll find working code.

Comment: Thank you, that works. But oddly, in my actual app, the backdrop covers the child, despite the backdrop having a `z-index` of 102, and the child having a `z-index` of 103. And child stays covered even as I fiddle with `z-index`es in DevTools. Parent is in an `iron-page` in a `app-drawer-layout`... But still I can't see why child is not on top.

Comment: @Thad I think it's a problem of stacking contexts. Probably parent element of   the hidden element creates new stacking context. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index) you can find more info about that.

Comment: Yes, that's it. In my app if I remove `placeholder`, size 'mychild1 directly, and call `document.body.appendChild(this.mychild);` it works. I've some more stuff to play with about it, but this is great. Thank you so much for your help. (BTW `placeholder` came about b/c other issues with `vaadin-grid`, which I'm addressing.)