# Focus on custom element when user clicks and create an overlay behind it

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, overlay, polymer-2.x

I have a custom element which takes input whenever user clicks on it I want to focus on it and create an overlay on other elements and when the user clicks outside the div I want to remove the overlay.

I am trying to do it using `iron-overlay-behavior` but not able to achieve the expected behavior.

```
<custom-element 
    with-backdrop 
    scroll-action="lock"
    clicked="{{isClicked}}"
></decision-view>
```

All the examples shown are mostly for `paper-dialog` but how can I use `iron-overlay-behavior` for a custom element of my own?

Answer (score 1):

The `iron-overlay-behavior` seems to be meant more for modal dialogs, what you are trying to accomplish is something different (for instance, modal dialogs are only shown one at a time, and *require* user input before going back to normal application/website behavior). So I think a natural thing for that behavior would be to disable anything else to focus!

When you say:

> create an overlay on other elements

what does that mean? Just paint white over them like they were not visible?

Comment: I mean reduce the Z-index of other elements and focus on the editable element lets say there is a paper input when I click or edit on it I want to elements above it and below it to have reduced Z-Index or to fade I hope you understood what I meant

Comment: Could it be you mix method and goal in your explanation? What would be the result for the user?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue last week. See [Showing a gray backdrop with a mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938226/showing-a-gray-backdrop-with-a-mixin/)
.

For a demo, see [this pen](https://codepen.io/stat92/pen/RQYvdv?editors=1000) from [Makha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6597980/makha):

```
<dom-module id="parent-component">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto auto auto;
        border: 2px solid gray;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100px;
      }
      [hidden] {
        display: none;
      }
      paper-button {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
      #placeholder {
        width: 120px;
        height: 150px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>Try me.</div>
    <paper-button on-tap="_doTap">Push</paper-button>
    <div id="placeholder" hidden></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    class ParentComponent extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'parent-component'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          mychild: {
            type: Object
          }
        }
      }
      _doTap(e) {
        let x = (e.detail.x - 50) + 'px';
        let y = (e.detail.y - 50) + 'px';
        this.mychild = new MyChild();
        this.mychild.addEventListener('return-event', e => this._closeChild(e));
        this.$.placeholder.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.$.placeholder.appendChild(this.mychild);
        this.$.placeholder.style.left = x;
        this.$.placeholder.style.top = y;
        this.$.placeholder.removeAttribute('hidden');
        this.mychild.open();
      }
      _closeChild(e) {
        console.log('Child says '+e.detail);
        this.mychild.remove();
        this.mychild = null;
        this.$.placeholder.setAttribute('hidden', '');
      }
    }
    customElements.define(ParentComponent.is, ParentComponent);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<parent-component></parent-component>

<dom-module id="my-child">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto auto auto;
        border: 2px solid gray;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      paper-button {
        background-color: lightgray;
      }
    </style>
    <div>I'm a child.</div>
    <paper-button on-tap="_doTap">Close</paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyChild extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior], Polymer.Element) {
      static get is() { return 'my-child'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
         withBackdrop: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: true
         }
        }
      }
      ready() {
        super.ready();
        console.log("Daddy?");
      }
      _doTap(e) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('return-event', 
                                           { detail: 'Bye!', bubbles: true, composed: true }));
      }
    }
    customElements.define(MyChild.is, MyChild);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```